# Swift-Can't convert core data to url parameters

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to build a small app that track device location. So save the location into core data. But can't convert it to json for sending this information to server. I got following errors

> 2018-12-18 13:08:33.583580+0530 My App[6696:144278] [General] An uncaught exception was raised.
>
> 2018-12-18 13:08:33.583605+0530 My App[6696:144278] [General] Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate).
>
> 2018-12-18 13:08:33.604814+0530 My App[6696:144278] [General] (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff4af112db __exceptionPreprocess + 171 ........)

Loading data from core data

```
func loadingFromCoreData() -> [String:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] 
{
        var locationsArray: [String:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>] = [:]
        var count = 0
        if let context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
            do {
                locationDataInstance = try context.fetch(LocationInformation.fetchRequest())
            } catch {

            }
        }
        print("IN Loading From database")
        for locationDI in locationDataInstance {
            var location_info: [String:AnyObject]=[:]
            location_info["latitude"] = locationDI.latitude as AnyObject
            location_info["longitude"] = locationDI.longitude as AnyObject
            location_info["timestamp"] = locationDI.timestamp as AnyObject
            locationsArray["\(count)"] = location_info
            count = count + 1
        }
        return locationsArray
}
```

Dictionary to Json coversion

```
    let parameters:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = ["name":devicename as AnyObject,"loctioninfo":loadingFromCoreData() as AnyObject]
    do {
        let js = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
        print(js)
    } catch {
        print(error.description)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: The type of `timestamp` is obviously `Date` and JSON does not support this type.

Add a computed property to convert the `Date` object to UNIX timestamp or date string for example

```
var unixTimeStamp : Double {
    return timestamp.timeIntervalSince1970
}
```

And get rid of this ugly `as AnyObject` cast by declaring the dictionary as `[String:Any]`